# Gremlin if else inside .by() function

Tags: c#, gremlin, janusgraph

I am using Gremlin.Net to connect to janus database, my question is about gremlin how can i perform the next query in case the the vertex with ***id = 61464 doesn't have father***. Its break out currently.
when I use this

```
g.V(61464).Project<object>("father", "mother", "children").
            By(Out("father")).
            By(Out("mother")).
            By(In("father").Fold()).Next();
```

if the selected vertex doesn't have a father the query break out, how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends a bit upon what you want to return in place of a "father". One way to deal with it is to use `coalesce()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('name','age').
......1>         by('name').
......2>         by(coalesce(values('age'),constant('none')))
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:lop,age:none]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:ripple,age:none]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

The `project()` step require the `by()` to return something. If you wanted to better shape your result and drop the irrelevant "age" property you could post filter the projected `Map`:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   project('name','age').
......2>     by('name').
......3>     by(coalesce(values('age'),constant('none'))).
......4>   local(unfold().
......5>         filter(select(values).is(P.neq('none'))).
......6>         group().
......7>           by(keys).
......8>           by(select(values).unfold()))
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:lop]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:ripple]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

Comment: Hi stephen, thanks for the answer, it solve my problem, can I remove the age in case of it doesn't exist?

Comment: That is great Thanks :)

Comment: cleaned up a bit more by unwrapping the inner lists in the map